# Modx Get page and sorting with &sortbyTV

Tags: modx

Ok, before anyone points me to the Modx RTFM, let me just say, that I've actually implemented this on a few sites, using getpage rather than just getresources and they have all worked according to my needs, and what those needs were was to give visitors the ability to sort a list according to a template variable.

Now in all instances I used a listbox (single select)template variable as so (in this case for rating):

```
1==[[$one_star]] || 1.5==[[$one_and_half]] || 2==[[$two_star]] || 2.5==[[$two_and_half]] || 3==[[$three_star]] || 3.5==[[$three_and_half]] || 4==[[$four_star]] || 4.5==[[$four_and_half]] || 5==[[$five_star]]
```

Now, on my current project which is days from launch, I created a template variable called "price", in which the numerical value is entered into a text field, nothing more and, for some reason, getpage doesn't return the proper output. For example on a "low to high" page the first in the list is not the lowest priced item.

here's an example of the call. (I use getpage for pagination)

```
[[!getPage? 
    &elementClass=`modSnippet` 
    &showHidden=`1` 
    &sortbyTV=`price` 
    &sortdirTV=`ASC` 
    &element=`getResources` 
    &parents=`7,8,9,10,11,12` 
    &limit=`8` 
    &pageLimit=`2` 
    &pageVarKey=`page` 
    &includeTVs=`1` 
    &includeContent=`1` 
    &tpl=`store_post` 
    &tvPrefix=`tv.` 
    &cache=`0`
]]
<div class="paging">
<ul class="pageList">
  [[!+page.nav]]
</ul>
</div>
```

and here's the template:

```
 <div class="product_info_container">
      <div class="product_name">[[+tv.product_name]]</div>
      <div class="product_details">[[+tv.product_details]]</div>
      <div class="product_price">price: [[+tv.price]] USD</div>
      <div class="product_purchase">[[+tv.pay_button]]</div>
      <div class="view_cart">[[$viewcart]]</div>
</div>
```

I'm on  Revolution 2.2.13-pl (I tried updating to 2.2.14 but there was a php error which scared the heck outta me and until I isolate the cause, with launch looming, I'm not touching it! :P) All packages are current as well.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated because, needless to say, I'm stumped :)

p.s. I know the above getpage call is for ASC not DESC...I was just using the low to high as an example

Comment: is it sorting by the price as text instead of numerically?

Comment: yes, exactly! I'm sorry I didn't respond sooner, I just never received an email notification that someone had responded.

For example, I enter prices in the template variable:
1
2
3
if I set it from high to low, it spits back:
3
2
1
but, if I enter prices as such:
17
19
169
it will return 
19
17
169
as if it first sorts the first digit, then the next, then the next, but not the entire numeric value.  Am I making sense? I think I confuse myself! :P

Comment: no great solution to this, see this thread: http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=43657&page=2
 Has a hack solution.

Comment: knowing it's going to sort by text, maybe prefixing with leading 0's is the easiest way to go.

Comment: Leading with a zero worked Avibodha! Thank you so much!

Comment: sortbyTVType=\`integer\` (this option defaults to "string")